# Join future dates to table which only has dates until current day

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have these two tables:

```
table1: name (string), actual (double), yyyy_mm_dd (date)
table2: name (string), expected(double), yyyy_mm_dd (string)
```

`table1` contains data from 2018-01-01 up until the current day, `table2` contains predicted data for the year of 2020. My problem is that `table1` doesn’t have any date values past the present date, so I get duplicate data when joining like below:

```
SELECT 
    kpi.yyyy_mm_dd,
    kpi.name,
    kpi.actual as actual,
    pre.predicted as predicted 
FROM
    schema1.table1 kpi
LEFT JOIN 
    schema1.table2 pre 
    ON name = kpi.name --AND pre.yyyy_mm_dd = kpi.yyyy_mm_dd
WHERE
     kpi.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-12-09'
```

Output:

```
+----------+------------+----------+-------------+
|yyyy_mm_dd|  name      |actual    |predicted    |
+----------+------------+----------+-------------+
|2019-12-10|  Company   | 100000   | 925,180     |
|2019-12-10|  Company   | 100000   | 1,145,723   |
|2019-12-10|  Company   | 100000   | 456,359     |
--------------------------------------------------
```

If I uncomment the `AND` condition in my join clause, I won’t get the predicted values as my first table has no 2020 data. How can I join these tables together without duplicating actual values? `actual` should be null for days which haven't happened yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want UNION ALL and not a JOIN:

```
SELECT 
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    name,
    actual as actual,
    NULL as predicted 
FROM schema1.table1
WHERE yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-12-09'
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    yyyy_mm_dd,
    name,
    NULL as actual,
    predicted as predicted 
FROM schema1.table2
```

Comment: I think a `union all` would work here, however in reality `table1` contains many metrics (`actual` is just one of them). `table2` only contains three columns. How could I union these since one schema would be larger than the other?

Comment: This is why I use NULL. The columns that do not exist in each table can be replaced with NULL at the other table.

Answer (score 0):

Hive supports `full join`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(kpi.yyyy_mm_dd, pre.yyyy_mm_dd) as yyyy_mm_dd,
       COALESCE(kpi.name, pre.name) as name,
       kpi.actual as actual,
       pre.predicted as predicted 
FROM (SELECT kpi.*
      FROM schema1.table1 kpi 
      WHERE kpi.yyyy_mm_dd >= '2019-12-09'
     ) kpi FULL JOIN
     schema1.table2 pre 
     ON kpi.name = pre.name AND
        kpi.yyyy_mm_dd = pre.yyyy_mm_dd
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
group by
```

clause in your query, below might solve your problem

```
SELECT 
    kpi.yyyy_mm_dd,
    kpi.name,
    kpi.actual as actual,
    pre.predicted as predicted 
FROM
    schema1.table1 kpi
LEFT JOIN 
    schema1.table2 pre 
    ON name = kpi.name
group by kpi.yyyy_mm_dd,kpi.name,kpi.actual
```